# bottomnavigationview forced shifting mode

Tags: java, android

From what I understand, the items in bottomnavigationview will automatically be put into shifting mode, where the icons enlarge and move when there are more than 3 items. Is the any way to force this behaviour?

Comment: So you want to hide label texts of inactive icons even if there are three items?

Comment: yes, and also have it animation the icons shifting around if possible

Comment: You can try [AHBottomNavigation](https://github.com/aurelhubert/ahbottomnavigation) library with a `bottomNavigation.setTitleState(AHBottomNavigation.TitleState.SHOW_WHEN_ACTIVE_FORCE);` call.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

`app:itemIconSize` to set menu icon size.

`app:labelVisibilityMode` to set the label mode.